# 12 Hour conversion using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to convert 24 hour to 12 hour format however my query is not resulting correct format

query:

```
select LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), getdate(), 100), 50))
```

Current output:

```
Oct  6 2018 10:46PM
```

Desired output:

```
2018-10-06 10:46:04.877
```

Any help?!

Comment: This doesn't seem reasonable.  Why would you want to make the time ambiguous?

Comment: With such a representation how could you tell 10AM from 10PM?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm', 'en-us')
```

`Output: 2018-10-07 03:02:31.02`

[For more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Try below way

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(), 108) 'hh:mi:ss'
```

Comment: I want the date also to show up. Pls chk desired output format in my question

Answer (score 0):

This format will give you the desired output

```
select CONVERT(varchar(50),GETDATE(),21) 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(12h)'
```

Comment: Not valid syntax.